# Is there any pratical difference for atom and null in Common Lisp if they receive a list as an argument?

Tags: null, logic, common-lisp

I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime. According to the book *Symbolic Computation: A gentle introduction to Common Lisp*, the definition of `atom` is:

> The ATOM predicate returns T if its input is anything other than a cons
> cell.

On the other hand:

> The NULL predicate returns T if its input is NIL. Its behavior is the same
> as the NOT predicate.

Using the REPL and taking **only lists** as arguments, I can only think of examples in which they retrieve the same results:

```lisp
CL-USER> (atom (cons 1 nil))
NIL
CL-USER> (null (cons 1 nil))
NIL
CL-USER> (atom (cons 1 (cons 2 nil))) 
NIL
CL-USER> (null (cons 1 (cons 2 nil))) 
NIL
CL-USER> (atom (cons 1 2))
NIL
CL-USER> (null (cons 1 2))
NIL
CL-USER> (atom '())
T
CL-USER> (null '())
T
CL-USER> (null nil) ;; just changing notation from previous
T
CL-USER> (atom nil) ;; just changing notation from previous
T
CL-USER> (atom '(1 . 2)) ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL
CL-USER> (null '(1 . 2)) ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL
CL-USER> (atom '(1 2))  ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL
CL-USER> (null '(1 2))  ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL 
CL-USER> (atom '(1))  ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL
CL-USER> (null '(1))  ;; just changing notation from previous
NIL
```

Based on the definitions, the examples above, and considering that **non-empty lists are cons cells**, I am concluding that:

> if the argument is a list, `null` and `atom` **do** have the same behavior as predicates.

Is there any counter-example for this statement? Did I miss something? Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is either:

- the empty list, `()` *aka* `nil`, which is not a cons;
- or a cons of any object and a list.

`null` returns true only for `nil`; `atom` returns true for any object which is not a cons.

Therefore, *when restricted to lists*, `null` and `atom` return true only for `nil`, being the only object which is both a list and not a cons, and are, for lists, equivalent predicates.